# Paying ransom a nonstarter in review of freeing captives?

Tags: meaning, headlinese

I read a headline like the following in today's newspaper.

> "Paying ransom a nonstarter in review of freeing captives"

I don't get it at all. Can somebody explain the structure of the sentence and its meaning?

Comment: It's a headline, and so, you probably should've copied in some of the relevant article so we can make a more educated guess. But, I think I can make a reasonable educated guess: *In a review of what can be done to free captives, it is not a good idea to attempt to pay a ransom to free them*. When we say something is a "non-starter", it often means that it is not an option, that it is not to be considered, that it can't be used to start a process, that it is not a good idea, etc.

Comment: Oh, "nonstarter" is in some dictionaries, and there's a sense of meaning like: "*informal:* a person, plan, or idea that has no chance of succeeding or being effective."

Comment: Let me reword that 1st comment of mine a bit: *In a review of what can be done to free captives, it was determined that it is not a good idea to pay a ransom to free them.*

Comment: @F.E. My answer was based on that. Not in some, in *many*, the non-starter word means what I thought of while writing my answer. But anyway, I attempted to answer it so that I learn. And, my sentence *whether to pay ransom to freeing captives should be reviewed first* is okay, I think.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, when you interpret headlines, you need to figure out what the missing words would be.

In this case, I'd expand the headline to:

> *Paying ransom **would be** a nonstarter in review of freeing captives*

In other words, imagine a room full of people discussing strategy:

> **Ed**: We want captives freed. What should we do?
>   **Ted**: Maybe we should pay the ransoms.
>   **Ned**: No, Ted, don't even go there. We're not even going to consider that.

If I was a reporter trying summarize that meeting, I might say:

> Paying ransom a nonstarter in review of freeing captives

---

Another way the headline could be expanded is by adding an *is*:

> *Paying ransom **is** a nonstarter in review of freeing captives*

This would align nicely with the definition of the word found in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/nonstarter):

> **non-starter** (*n.*) a worthless idea